# How can I forcibly kill a process using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, process

I have a process I'd like to kill:

```
$ ps Sourcetree

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1311     116   136720     137804      57.45   1044   1 SourceTree
```

Send it to [`Stop-Process`, aka `kill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177004.aspx):

```
$ ps Sourcetree | kill
```

Runs without error. But the process isn't killed:

```
$ ps Sourcetree

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1311     116   136720     137804      57.45   1044   1 SourceTree
```

**How can I forcibly kill a process using powershell?**

Comment: `stop-process -force`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 For some reason the docs I found doesn't include the -force, but you're right - list that as an answer (with a link to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) and I;ll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-Force`.

```
ps -force Sourcetree | kill
```

Taken from [help Stop-Process -online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Stop-Process)

```
Stop-Process [-Id] <Int32[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

-Force

Stops the specified processes without prompting for confirmation.
By default, Stop-Process prompts for confirmation before stopping
any process that is not owned by the current user.

To find the owner of a process, use the Get-WmiObject cmdlet to
get a Win32_Process object that represents the process, and then
use the GetOwner method of the object.
Type: SwitchParameter
Parameter Sets: (All)
Aliases: 

Required: False
Position: Named
Default value: None
Accept pipeline input: False
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

Bonus nachos, `Get-Command -ParameterName *force` will show all Cmdlets that include the **force** param.

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent to taskkill /f, or "kill -9" in unix.  There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way.

Comment: I think that -force parameter goes for the Kill cmdlet, not for ps (Get-Process)

ps Sourcetree | kill -force

Answer (score 1):

if you do it?

```
(get-process -Name SourceTree).Kill()
```

Comment: Doesn't kill it. I needed `-force` per accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand cmdlets and what they do you can always do `Get-Help cmdlet` and look what it does\supports.

```
Get-Help Stop-Process
```

or just enter the cmdlet into the search engine, that will most likely lead you to a official help article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process